# How do I enable touch swipe feature in a carousel?

Tags: jquery, touch, carousel

I have a carousel on my web page but i need the touch swipe feature for mobile devices. How can I enable this feature? My site also using `jQuery UI Touch Punch`

```
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.caroufredsel
```

I am trying this

```
     $ (function () {
      carousel var = $ ('# carouFredSel'). carouFredSel ({   
            circular: true,
            infinite: true,
            swipe: {
                onMouse: true,
                OnTouch: true
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the same thing a week ago. you may have a look here:

https://doclerchat.herokuapp.com/

I'm making use of bootstrap to make a carousel and for swipe feature I'm using jQuery mobile which is pretty straightforward to use to use.

this is my slider:

```
<div id="photos" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div id="img-slider" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/1/></div>
            <div class="item"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/2/></div>
            <div class="item"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/3/></div>
            <div class="item"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/4/></div>
            <div class="item"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/5/></div>
            <div class="item"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/6/></div>
            <div class="item"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/7/></div>
            <div class="item"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/8/></div>
            <div class="item"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/9/></div>
            <div class="item"><img src=http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/city/10/></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#img-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#img-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery code to implement swipe:

```
   var $slider = $('#img-slider');

   $slider.on( "swipeleft", function(){ // show next image on swipe left
        if($('.carousel-inner .item:last').hasClass('active')){
            $('#img-slider').carousel('pause');
        } else{
            $('#img-slider').carousel('next');
        }

    }).on( "swiperight", function(){ // show prev image on swipe right
        if($('.carousel-inner .item:first').hasClass('active')){
            $('#img-slider').carousel('pause');
        } else{
            $('#img-slider').carousel('prev');
        }
    });
```

you can have a look at the full applicaiton here: https://github.com/anshul119/chatapp-source

Comment: I am using carouFredSel not bootstrap

Comment: you can still use jquery Mobile to add gesture support. Simply change the IDs and classes I have used in jquery code according to your needs. Else create a fiddle and I will do it for you :)